# How to override array in Typesafe config with environment variables?

Tags: typesafe, typesafe-config

I've been using the [environment variable substitution](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides) feature in Typesafe config:

```
foo = "foo"
foo = ${?FOO}
```

This results in a "default" value of "foo" if there is no environment variable named `FOO`. In this case, the second value declaration (`foo = ${?FOO}` is simply discarded). However, if a variable named `FOO` exists, the library will "substitute" the value of `FOO` and assign it to `foo`.

I would like similar behavior with arrays, but unfortunately, this does not work as expected:

```
foo = [ "1", "2" ]
foo = [ ${?f1}, ${?f2} ]
```

In the case where `f1` and `f2` are not defined, this simply results in `foo` being an empty array. My goal is to have a similar effect as above (discard the second `foo` if no environment variables `f1` and `f2` are defined). Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not ideal, but if you're able to handle this in application code, could you append the defaults to the optional values from the environment, and then do e.g. a length check? `foo = [ ${?f1}, ${?f2} ]` `foo += "1"` `foo += "2"`

The above will give you anything set in the environment followed by the two defaults. You could also start with an empty array for `foo` and append in the two environment variables too.

Answer (score 7):

I found that using `a = ${?VARNAME}` in the HOCON config file with the Scala code expecting a `List`, and using `-DVARNAME.0=something` (or simply `VARNAME.0=something`) will result in the correct `["something"]` value. (Tested with Play 2.6.13 and the AllowedHosts filter.)

Comment: What if the array value is object ? would `-DVARNAME.0.fieldName=something` work, or should I pass the whole object ?

Comment: @Can yes, I believe that's what I did to get something similar to work.

Comment: Is there a version of this that works with environment variables?  I can't easily change the command line, and I definitely can't change the number of flags I pass on the command line.

Comment: @TroyDaniels do you want to pass in env vars like `-DVARNAME.0.fieldName=$EnvVar` ?